# runtime exception must include listview with attribute android.R.id.list

Tags: android, listview

> my program contains a listview for retrieving database data . but the code is not working. the xml files and logcat are given below.pls help me.
>   my program contains a listview for retrieving database data . but the code is not working. the xml files and logcat are given below.pls help me

```
package example.showevent1;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

class Getclicker  extends ListActivity {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String datevalue = intent.getStringExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Userselectvalue = intent.getStringExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
    classdbOpenHelper eventsData1;
    Cursor cursor1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);                        /*String datevalue = date.getText().toString();
        String Userselectvalue = userSelection.getText().toString();

        String showevent = eventsData.getContact(datevalue,Userselectvalue);
        show.setText(showevent);*/

         cursor1 = eventsData1.getContact(datevalue,Userselectvalue);
         String[] fromColumns = {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT};
         int[] toViews = {R.id.event};
         SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.events, cursor1, fromColumns, toViews,0 );
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    public void onDestroy() {
        eventsData1.close();
      }

}
```

> activity_first.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/color_1"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Add Event" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="ShowEvent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#b22924" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="@string/select"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#b22924"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="Select A Place" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:text="@string/dt" />
  <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> logcat

```
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.showevent1/example.showevent1.FirstActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at example.showevent1.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:56)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-07 06:46:14.565: E/AndroidRuntime(3633):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: you have asked 11 questions accepted none? does none of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

Every ListActivity needs a default ListView id in it's layout definition so instead of your ListView id :

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

use :

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: i dont' know! maybe because of your comment on another question

Comment: i don't see any thing wrong with the answer i upvoted it. i will delete my comment

Comment: Thank you anyway i also deleted that answer ;)

Comment: @Raghunandan : It's downvoted (by me) because `@id/android:list` is wrong. It should be `@android:id/list`

Comment: @Squonk nice you pointed the mistake i failed to notice. thank you.

Comment: @Arash you need to change this `<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"` to   `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"`. for clarity check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. pls edit your answer.

Comment: @Squonk and Raghunandan : Thank you for your comments i've edited my answer but can you explain why it's wrong? my codes work just fine with this id!

Comment: @Arash http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. check the topic under id section

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

Add the below to listview in xml

```
   <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

To initialize listview

```
   ListView listView = getListView();
```

Comment: @HossamOukli op has  this `<ListView android:id="@+id/list"` not  `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

To this:

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

in your XML file. Hope it helps.

Comment: you are wrong it must be `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"` and not `<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html